# Select element based on condition using Javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a jQuery statement as;

```
$("a[target="+iframeId+"]").attr("href", url);
```

What is the best way to write this in normal Javascript DOM such that the perofrmance is not affected much?

Comment: Also to add..cross-browser compatible code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it, though the jquery method is almost assuredly faster:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (links[i].getAttribute("target") == iframeId) {
        links[i].setAttribute("href", url);
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be worth testing whether `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` is available. Then you can get the elements with `document.querySelectorAll('a[target="+iframeId+"]')`.